# How to create a Registration Review/Approval Process in .net Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm looking for a way to implement a review process when people register for my app.

I'm using .net Core with Identity and using AzureAD(OpenIdConnect), Social,  and basic Usernames and Passwords as my authentication sources.

If someone logs in from the Azure AD tenant of the owning organization e.g. bob_teacher@teachcorp.com using AzureAD I register them automatically and give them access right away.

If this is a teacher from a different approved school, e.g. sara@betterskool.com then they would also be registered, but not get access, just get a profile.

I would then have an admin approve their access.

This is useful when I want to be able to assign a Teacher to a Class but not give them access, e.g. until they have their security checks complete.

There is also the case that depending on the type of person they are assigned a particular identity class. e.g. Teacher, Student, Parent. which drives certain business logic.

Another challenge is that I currently have a lot of non-access users, such as Students in the system who are derived from IdentityUser, so just looking at something like IsActive is a bit of a pain.

I'm thinking that there are a few options, e.g.

1. I could create an invite type approach which would create an invite ticket and send an email, this would then be used to automatically give them appropriate access on registration using that ticket.
2. The access could be controlled from Azure AD using roles or claims. This would work for all those in the Organization as long as Azure AD is used as the source of truth, this is fine for users in my Azure AD org.
3. I can add a status field on the user which can be used to drive a simple business process, e.g. they are "For Approval" when registered.  Where an admin is notified of a new user and a screen which displays the "For Approval" users.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's implemented at the moment as mentioned, When an AD user logins; if they do not have an existing profile this is created, but is set as inactive. I can also create users through the system and send them an email to login as per the Identity framework.  I have custom SPs to change the types which can be performed by an admin.  It's clunky more than anything.  My question is really about design than implementation as to code these is pretty significant, so it would be good to see what people have done and feedback before I go ahead and create the workflow.

Comment: I prefer to use claims and roles which are used to permission control.Refer to https://hackernoon.com/permission-based-authorization-asp-net-core-with-authorizationpolicyprovider-af4933d575ee